# Sum value when satisfy condition in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get sum of values when certain condition is satisfied in the document. 
In the below query i want to get sum of currentValue only when componentId = "ABC"

```
db.Pointnext_Activities.aggregate( 
{ $project: {        
    _id: 0, 
    componentId:1,
    currentValue:1
        }
},
{ $group: 
    { _id: "$componentId", 
        total: { $sum: "$currentValue" } 
    } 
} 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
db.Pointnext_Activities.aggregate([{ $match: { componentId: 'ABC' } },
{
    $group:
    {
        _id: "$componentId",
        total: { $sum: "$currentValue" }
    }
}, { $project: { 'componentId': '$_id', total: 1, _id: 0 } }])
```

If you just need the total value & doesn't care about **componentId** to be returned try this :

```
db.Pointnext_Activities.aggregate([{ $match: { componentId: 'ABC' } },
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id: "",
            total: { $sum: "$currentValue" }
        }
    }, {$project :{total :1, _id:0}}])
```

It would be ideal in aggregation, if you always start with filter operation i.e; `$match`, as it would persist only needed documents for further steps.